# Format dynamic data using awk

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm trying to format a dynamic data but it's not working. May i know what am i missing.

```
echo "============================================================================================================="
awk 'BEGIN {printf "%-25s %-5s %-20s %-5s %-5s %-20s %-3s %-3s\n", "Vol_Name","Capacity","Pool","Used Capacity","Locked","WWN(LUND ID)","Mirrored","Status"}'
echo "============================================================================================================="

grep -iE $lunid ${XIV_TEMP}/lunid_* | awk '{printf "%-25s %-5s %-20s %-5s %-5s %-20s %-3s %-3s\n", $1, $2, $3, $6, $12, $14, $15, $29}'
```

The output is not aligned and as expected.

```
=============================================================================================================
Vol_Name                  Capacity Pool                 Used Capacity Locked WWN(LUND ID)         Mirrored Status
=============================================================================================================
glbprodssq_cl_1_svm_011   326   XIV_SM1-GBL_PROD_SVM 319   no    01173900AEC601AF     yes no
```

Expected output:

```
============================================================================================================================
        Vol_Name         Capacity       Pool            Used Capacity   Locked      WWN(LUND ID)         Mirrored   Status
============================================================================================================================
glbprodssq_cl_1_svm_011    326   XIV_SM1-GBL_PROD_SVM       319           no     01173900AEC601AF          yes      online
```

Answer (score 0):

You are exceeding the number of characters of the string. If you specify '%-5s', this means that the string is padded by spaces at the right till the string is 5 characters long. If you exceed that, it will break the formatting. For a better way of formatting tables I would look at column command.

Answer (score 0):

I found this-http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html very helpful! I found it trying to answer your question.

Especially,

'The last example places spaces before each field to make sure the minimum field width is met. What do you do if you want the spaces on the right? Add a negative sign before the width:

```
printf("%-10s %-6d\n", $1, $2);
```

This will move the printing characters to the left, with spaces added to the right.'

I agree with the other answer also.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what you want when the width of a field is incorrect.
You can change the width or choose for something like

```
;-> printf "|%.5s|\n" 123 12345 1234567
|123|
|12345|
|12345|
;-> printf "|%5s|\n" 123 12345 1234567
|  123|
|12345|
|1234567|
;-> printf "|%-5s|\n" 123 12345 1234567
|123  |
|12345|
|1234567|
;-> printf "|%5.5s|\n" 123 12345 1234567
|  123|
|12345|
|12345|
;-> printf "|%-5.5s|\n" 123 12345 1234567
|123  |
|12345|
|12345|
```